# C# ObjectListView TreeListView - How to highlight items only in TreeViewList other than using ModelFilter

Tags: c#, filtering, objectlistview, treelistview

I'm using ObjectListView.Official.2.9.1.nupkg
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html
Here is my sample code:  [C# ObjectListView TreeListView add multi-level Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334648/c-sharp-objectlistview-treelistview-add-multi-level-nodes)
Currently I'm using **ModelFilter** and the problem was when i perform **Collapse**, the nodes went missing.
Explanation: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html#filtering-and-treelistviews

```
private void txtSearchInTable_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtSearchInTable.Text == "")
        {
            this.treeListView1.ResetColumnFiltering();
            treeListView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        else
        {
            this.treeListView1.ModelFilter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(this.treeListView1, txtSearchInTable.Text);
            this.treeListView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex + "", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Is there any function for search and **highlight text only** while keeping everything visible?

**Update:**

```
TextMatchFilter filter1 = TextMatchFilter.Contains(treeListView1, txtSearchInTable.Text);
filter1.Columns = new[] { this.olvColumn1, this.olvColumn2, this.olvColumn3, this.olvColumn4 };
treeListView1.DefaultRenderer = new HighlightTextRenderer(filter1);
```

Using DefaultRenderer it's work, but why only first column "olvColumn1" cannot be highlighted? even I set **olvColumn1.Searchable = true;**

Comment: According to [comment on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/bugs/145/), TreeListView has its own renderer for first column, so your own does not apply. But this one has highlighting built-in. Just set its filter, `treeListView1.TreeColumnRenderer.Filter = filter1`

Comment: @Dialecticus Interesting, I included this information to my answer.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thanks. This solve my problem. Not sure why treeListView1 must be active in order to highlight after txtSearchInTable_TextChanged, so i just added another line `this.treeListView1.Refresh();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HighlightTextRenderer](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#highlighttextrenderer) to highlight and optionally filter items.

[image]

As pointed out by *Dialecticus* in one of the comments, the first column of a **TreeListView** (in contrast to **ObjectListView**) requires special handling.

Quote from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/bugs/145/):

> On a **TreeListView**, the **DefaultRenderer** is used for all columns except the first. The first column is drawn by the **TreeColumnRenderer**, which has to be an instance of **TreeRenderer**. **TreeRenderer** already supports text highlighting. You just need to change the **Filter** property.

> So your code just needs to add a single line to update the **Filter** property:

```
TextMatchFilter filter = new TextMatchFilter(this.treeListView1, toolStripTextBox1.Text);
this.treeListView1.DefaultRenderer = new HighlightTextRenderer(filter);
this.treeListView1.TreeColumnRenderer.Filter = filter;
```

Comment: I tried this before but still not working, this function same as ModelFilter.

Comment: @Josh do not set `ModelFilter`. Set only `DefaultRenderer`.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thanks. Please check my **update** for problem when using DefaultRenderer only.